# How to autoscale jawsdb database when traffic goes high

Tags: jawsdb-maria

How to autoscale jawsdb database when traffic goes high

i have not tried with it

When the events like BFCM come we need to upgrade the database cluster in digital ocean.

So, how i can scale up the jawsdb database if we move our application on heroku?

Thanks!!